# Munin doesn't show new host when using munin-cgi-html

Tags: munin

A few months ago, I switched from running Munin in static `munin-cron` mode to dynamic `munin-html-cgi` mode, but now when I add a new host to monitor it, it doesn't show up in the generated HTML, even though I can see that it is receiving the new data (in `/var/lib/munin`).

Am I missing something?

I'm using Munin 2.0.9 on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `munin-html-cgi` was somehow using cached data from when Munin used to run in static mode. Removing `/var/lib/munin/htmlconf.storable` and restarting `munin-html-cgi` fixed the issue.